# XQuery : how to try if a list contains a given string?

Tags: xml, xquery, contains

I have 2 XML files :

file1.xml

```
<data>doe90</data>
<data>foo</data>
<data>goo</data>
...
```

file2.xml

```
<data2>nan</data2>
<data2>goo</data2>
<data2>test</data2>
...
```

I stored this data in 2 vars :

```
let $data := //data,
$data2 := //data2
```

And began to do this :

```
for $d in $data2
return 
if() (: $d is also in $data ? :)
```

What should I do ? Thanks

EDIT : Of course I tried contains, but got an error :

```
if(contains($d,$data) = 0)
```

> An exception occurred during query execution: XPTY0004: cannot convert
>   'xs:boolean(true)' to xs:integer

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This may help:

```
//data[. = //data2] ► returns elements whose string values are contained in data2 
//data = //data2    ► returns true there are any matches, false otherwise
```

fn:contains() won’t help here, as it was built for matching [substrings](http://www.xqueryfunctions.com/xq/fn_contains.html):

```
contains('abc', 'a') ► true
```

Comment: How can I get data that is not in //data2 ? I tried `//data[. != //data2]` but got the same result.

Comment: `//data[. != //data2]` will return true if there is at least one combination that matches. Try `//data[not(. = //data2)]` instead.

Answer (score 3):

Contains only works on strings. (although in your example it seems to convert the nodes to strings, but then fails, because it returns boolean which you cannot compare to 0.  )

You can do

```
if (exists(index-of($data, $d)))
```

And

```
$data2[exists(index-of($data, .))]
```

is probably faster than the for/if- (but still n^2)

Comment: $data (the sequence) should come first

Comment: `$data2[exists(index-of($data, .))]` works for data that's in $data, how to proceed to get data that is not into it ?

Comment: Use `empty` instead of `exists`. Although Christians answer is probably better

Answer (score 0):

This work for me:

```
fn:exists($data[. =($data2/text())])
```

Comment: This answer actually provides nothing which is not already given in Christian Grüns answer. There is no need to use `text()` as the atomic value will be used anyway for the comparison. Which basically makes it `$data[. = $data]`, so the same as Christians answer. The exists() only checks if there is at least one result. However, in general it is better (faster and easier readable) to drop the whole if comparison and use the simply query Christian proposed instead. Nevertheless, welcome to SO!