# Xquery - How to match two sequences within a quantifier expression

Tags: xquery, contains

Like many, I'm tackling the Mondial database on XML. It would be a piece of cake, if XQuery syntax wasn't doing its best to sabotage.

```
let $inland := //province/@id
where every $sea in //sea satisfies
$sea/located/@province != $inland
return $inland
```

What I am trying to do in the above is find all "inland" provinces, the provinces that **don't** have a sea next to it. This, however, doesn't work, because the $sea/located/province is a big string, with every single province that it borders in it.

So I tried to modify into.

```
let $inland := //province/@id
where every $sea in //sea satisfies
not(contains($sea/located/@province, $inland))
return $inland
```

Where I would like it to only find the provinces that are a part of the sea's bordering provinces. Simple and straightforward.

Error message:

```
Stopped at C:/Users/saffekaffe/Desktop/mondial/xml/country_without_island.xml, 2/1:
[XPTY0004] Item expected, sequence found: (attribute id {"prov-Greece-2"},....
```

How do I get around this?

Example of //sea/located/province@

```
province="prov-France-5 prov-France-20 prov-France-89 prov-France-99"
```

Example of //province/@id

```
id="prov-Greece-2"
```

Comment: Not sure it's your current error, but XQuery must returned well-formed XML, which sequences of well-formed XML aren't (no root tag) ; try `return <result>{$inland}</result>` maybe?

Comment: It errors specifically at the comma in the contains function. Thank you for the suggestion anyway.

Comment: Right, contains is a string function which expects a string and a potential substring rather than a sequence and a potential element. [This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13979691/xquery-how-to-try-if-a-list-contains-a-given-string) should help.

Comment: I see what they did there @Aaron but it isn't quite enough, I need to be able to match against a substring a province with name "province2" and a sea that borders both "province2 province4" for example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are multiple ways in which XQuery works in a different way than you seem to expect.

1. The comparison operators `=` and `!=` have *existential semantics* if at least one of their arguments is a *sequence* instead of a single item. This means that `$seq1 = $seq2` is equivalent to `some $x in $seq1, $y in $seq2 satisfies $x = $y`. The query `('foo', 'bar') = ('bar', 'baz', 'quuz')` returns `true` because there is at least one common item.
2. An XQuery exception like `//province/@id` evaluates to a *sequence* of all matching nodes. In your case that would be a sequence of over 1000 province IDs: `(id="prov-cid-cia-Greece-2", id="prov-cid-cia-Greece-3", id="prov-cid-cia-Greece-4", [...])`. This sequence is then bound to the variable `$inland` in your `let` clause. Since you don't iterate over individual items in `$inland` (for example using a `for` clause), the `where` condition then works on the whole sequence of all provinces worldwide at once. So your condition `every $sea in //sea satisfies
   $sea/located/@province != $inland` now means:
   "For every `sea` there is a `province` located next to it that has an `@id` that is not equal to *at least one of all existing province IDs*."
   Th is returns `false` because there are `sea`s with no `located` children, e.g.the *Gulf of Aden*.
3. `contains($str, $sub)` is not a good fit for checking if a substring is contained in a space-delimited string, because it also matches parts of entries: `contains("foobar baz quux", "oob")` returns `true`.
   Instead you should either split the string into its parts using `tokenize($str)` and look through its parts, or use `contains-token($str, $token)`.

Putting it all together, a correct query very similar to your original one is:

```
for $inland in //province/@id
where
  every $sea in //sea
  satisfies not(contains-token($sea/located/@province, $inland))
return $inland
```

Another approach would be to first gather all (unique) provinces that are next to `sea`s and then return all provinces not in that sequence:

```
let $next-to-sea := distinct-values(//sea/located/@province/tokenize(.))
return //province/@id[not(. = $next-to-sea)]
```

Even more compact (but potentially less efficient):

```
//province/@id[not(. = //sea/located/@province/tokenize(.))]
```

On the other end of the spectrum you can use XQuery 3.0 *maps* to replace the potentially linear search through all seaside provinces by a single lookup:

```
let $seaside :=
  map:merge(
    for $id in //sea/located/@province/tokenize(.)
    return map{ $id: () }
  )
return //province/@id[not(map:contains($seaside, .))]
```

Comment: Thanks a million! That answers a lot of things simultaneously, good information :)